# Prove that If $p$ is prime s.t. $0<n\leq p$ , then $p|[{p! \over {(p-n)!(n)!}}]$.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that If $p$ is prime s.t. $0<n\leq p$ , then $p|[{p! \over {(p-n)!(n)!}}]$.
 I know that if $p|q$ , then $q=kp$, for some integer number $k$.
 But I don’t know how to prove that $p$ divided like above.
Is it working to use proof by induction?

Comment: Hint:  what's the highest power of $p$ that divides $p!$  ?  What about $(p-n)!$ or $n!$?

Comment: The claim is true for $0<n<p$, but not for $p=n$, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

$(p-n)!$ and $n!$ do not contain $p$ as a factor, so neither of them can divide $p$.  However $\binom{p}{n}$ is an integer, containing $p$ as a factor.  So $p$ divides $\binom{p}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint (assuming you have $n<p$): Show that $p$ does divide the numerator, but doesn't divide either of the factors in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

- $p\mid p!$, since $p!=p\cdot (p-1)!$
- If $p\mid (p-n)!$, then $p$ divides atleast one of the factors $p-n, p-(n+1), 3, 2, 1$. But this is impossible, since they are all less than $p$. Same argument with $n!$. Since $p$ is a prime number, $p\not\mid (p-n)!n!$.